# Should a non EU student with an EU state study visa still apply for a study visa of another EU country?

Tags: visa, student-visa, schengen, portugal, finland

I am a South Korean university student studying in Finland holding a Finnish student visa. I am going to Portugal for Erasmus semester and will be staying there for 4 months. Should I obtain a Portuguese study visa before I leave even though I already have a student visa of Finland which is in the Schengen area as Portugal?

Comment: The Finnish student visa allows you to stay in Portugal up to 3 months, anything beyond that you'll have to get a Portuguese student visa.